# How can I add a REGEX match to my J2ME project?

Tags: java, regex, java-me

The question pretty much sums it up.  Just want to run a regular expression match on a string in J2ME.

Comment: It might be worth editing your question to clarify the fact that the regex package is not part of the Java ME distribution, so that nobody says "well just use the Pattern class...".

Comment: I would have thought that it being J2ME you'd be able to find a more optimzed way of doing it unless you're taking a regexp as input from a user.

Answer (score 2):

JRegex will not run on CLDC device. Try this one: [code.google.com/p/regexp-me/](http://code.google.com/p/regexp-me/).

Answer (score 1):

Will [JRegex](http://jregex.sourceforge.net/) run in J2ME?

UPDATE: Based on Rory's comment, I recommend JRegex, then.

Comment: According to the site: JRegex is portable (runs under any version of java)

Answer (score 0):

JRegex doesn't compile on J2ME (at least in the blackberry dev environment).  I'm interested in a regex library as well but JRegex doesn't seem to work for this purpose.

Comment: This isn't really an answer.  Perhaps you meant to comment on one of the answers regarding JRegex?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what runs on J2ME due to the *extreme* old age of J2ME's API support, but try [Apache ORO](http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/index.html).  That's sufficiently old, crusty and obsolete that it *may*, if you're lucky, work on J2ME.