# JavaME: Convert String to camelCase

Tags: string, java-me, camelcasing

What would be a simple implementation of a method to convert a String like "Hello there everyone" to "helloThereEveryone". In JavaME support for String and StringBuffer utility operations are quite limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick primitive implementation. I have no idea of restrictions of J2ME, so I hope it fits or it gives some ideas...

```
String str = "Hello, there, everyone?";

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(str.length());
String strl = str.toLowerCase();
boolean bMustCapitalize = false;
for (int i = 0; i < strl.length(); i++)
{
  char c = strl.charAt(i);
  if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
  {
    if (bMustCapitalize)
    {
      result.append(strl.substring(i, i+1).toUpperCase());
      bMustCapitalize = false;
    }
    else
    {
      result.append(c);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    bMustCapitalize = true;
  }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

You can replace the convoluted uppercase append with:

```
result.append((char) (c - 0x20));
```

although it might seem more hackish.

Comment: Some J2ME implementations have extensions for alternate character sets.  If this is a concern, you really need to follow the platform's recommendations for collation, so the char math trick won't work on those character sets.

Comment: I would suggest avoid creating new strings here

result.append(strl.substring(i, i+1).toUpperCase());
And use 
result.append(Character.toUpperCase(c)); 
instead

Comment: @user655419 That's more or less what I suggest in the last paragraph, but with a less hackish solution, so thanks for the suggestion. Today, I would use a StringBuilder, too. Again, not sure if it works in JavaME, but this one is a bit obsoleted today, and the above code is still valid for Java SE.

Answer (score 1):

With CDC, you have:

String.getBytes();//to convert the string to an array of bytes
String.indexOf(int ch); //for locating the beginning of the words
String.trim();//to remove spaces

For lower/uppercase you need to add(subtract) 32.

With these elements, you can build your own method.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static String toCamelCase(String s) {
    String result = "";
    String[] tokens = s.split("_"); // or whatever the divider is
    for (int i = 0, L = tokens.length; i<L; i++) {
        String token = tokens[i];
        if (i==0) result = token.toLowerCase();
        else
            result += token.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
                token.substring(1, token.length()).toLowerCase();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

May be if you can [port one regexp library on J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121988/how-can-i-add-a-regex-match-to-my-j2me-project), you could use it to strip spaces in your String...

Comment: Good suggestion, but problematic due to licensing issues.

Comment: Won't perform the camel-case operation, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
public static String toCamel(String str) {
    String rtn = str;
    rtn = rtn.toLowerCase();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("_([a-z]{1})").matcher(rtn);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1).toUpperCase());
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    rtn = sb.toString();
    return rtn;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest the following simple code:

```
    String camelCased = "";
    String[] tokens = inputString.split("\\s");
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        String token = tokens[i];
        camelCased = camelCased + token.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + token.substring(1, token.length());
    }
    return camelCased;
```

Comment: @AustinHenley - I think because it doesn't work.  What if you had AIR FOIL as input?  What would the output be?  Based on my reading, it would be AIRFOIL. Which seems wrong.

Answer (score -2):

I would do it like this:

```
private String toCamelCase(String s) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String[] x = s.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", " ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
            .trim().split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            x[i] = x[i].toLowerCase();
        } else {
            String r = x[i].substring(1);
            x[i] = String.valueOf(x[i].charAt(0)).toUpperCase() + r;

        }
        sb.append(x[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

check this

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.WordUtils;

String camel = WordUtils.capitalizeFully('I WANT TO BE A CAMEL', new char[]{' '});

return camel.replaceAll(" ", "");
```